# Android: Icon Size for a custom layout

Tags: android, icons

I want to build an interface that is similar to Go Weather Ex application , link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex.gowidget.weatherwidget.

My problem is that I do not know the icons size (6 icons at the bottom) that is used. I followed this guideline http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html, but it speaks only about actionbar icons, lancher icons, notification icons.... So the question is what size i choose for a custom icon ?

Go Weather Ex application are using an horizontalscrollview layout with ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

You can import an imagen with pixels you want. You can do manually, so you should put the same imagen with diferent size in the follow drawable directories:

```
drawable-hdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
```

I usually create a "Android Icon Set" from(File->New->Other->Android), then select Launcher Icons, Image tab, and import the image, when you finish automatically the image will be import in drawwable-XXX directories.(Eclipe IDE)
I hope help you.

Comment: Thanks!! But my qustion is not about how to create icons, but more about the size that is used QWE application. By the way, there is a good tool to generate icons here: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5%2C100&name=ic_example

Comment: Well, you should create your imagen with a ideal size, you can try modify the pixels until get the perfect size for you, and then import the imagery(remember follow the ratio scaling for imagery look well in the others screen sizes) http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: ok i will try it. I tought if i choose a random size, my application will be rejected.

Comment: it's work for me. You should put a <ImagenView> in your xml, its layout_height and layout_width are wrap_content,then in android:src put the address of imagen.

Answer (score 0):

its 65x65 try this icon size for xhdpi.

Comment: Is it 65x65 full Asset or optical square (with pading)?

Comment: its the square of 65x65 with some padding on all four side of image.